# Error while moving bower to npm in ember project

Tags: npm, node-modules, upgrade, bower, ember-cli

I was trying to move all the bower packages as npm packages as part of our ember upgrade process.

Updated cli from 3.0.0 to 3.22 successfully.

While trying to move sweetalert2 from bower to npm using the below steps.

```
  bower uninstall sweetalert2 --save //remove the package and remove from bower.json also
  npm install sweetalert2 --save-dev //add as npm package and add in package.json also
  ember s
```

While building project it throws the following error.

```
Build Error (SourceMapConcat)

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-5259Sy2X7u6LvqKk/out-854-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/bower_components/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
```

Can anyone help me with this?